# regression on multiple roles per person

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, predictor

I'm working on a regression of a data set that involves people playing multiple roles. For example, a single person can be a manager, a department head, and a corporate officer at the same time. I want to understand how each of these roles factor into total compensation per employee. My initial approach was to have a data point for each person in each role and the total compensation for the person. eg:

```
EmpID TotalCmpValue  Role1 Role2 Role3 Role4
1     100000.0       1     1     1     1
2     50000.0        0     0     0     1
3     50000.0        0     1     1     0
```

This DOES produce results, but i suspect that its not correct. Do i need to create a discrete varaible/column for each viable combination of roles? eg:

```
EmpID TotalCmpValue  Role1234 Role4Only Role23
1     100000.0       1        0         0
2     50000.0        0        1         0
3     50000.0        0        0         1
```

Also, is there a term that describes the nature of this problem?

thanks

EDIT: After some additional research, i stumbled on the term multicoliniarity. Im pretty sure that ive explicitly introduced multicolinearity into my model and will work on modifying mo data model for roles to make them mutually exclusive... something like my second example